# Can't implement interface member 'IStoreListener'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I tried to upgrade UNITY from 2019.1.8f1 to 2019.2.13f1, and started to get a lot of compiler errors about IAP
also upgraded IAP to the latest version
-Can't implement interface member 'IStoreListener'
using UnityEngine.Purchasing.Security -The name security does not exist in the namespace

I downgraded back to 2019.1.8f1 but having the same error
I'm currently stuck with my project. Everything was perfect until that update :\

Comment: The api probably changed. Check the docs to see how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: By IAP you refer to the package [`Ads IAP Mediation Adaptor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ads.mediation@1.0/manual/index.html) imported through the PackageManager?

Comment: Try readding the package usung the package manager

Comment: You are most certainly using [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 4):

Replace your OnInitializeFailed Function code with this one

```
public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
        {
            Debug.Log(error);
        }



    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error, string? message = null)
    {
        var errorMessage = $"Purchasing failed to initialize. Reason: {error}.";

        if (message != null)
        {
            errorMessage += $" More details: {message}";
        }

        Debug.Log(errorMessage);
    }
```